# Drawing a line with a ruler

Tags: calculation-puzzle, mechanical-puzzles

Imagine we have a ruler on which just numbers 0 and 2 and 5 are marked and the rest numbers are erased. How could we draw a 6 cm line by this ruler?

Comment: Is this your own puzzle or did you find somewhere else? If so, kindly provide the source.

Comment: I found this somewhere else but I don't know the main source

Comment: Hi Rahim. Where was this 'somewhere else', please? All puzzles from elsewhere do need to have a source stated, even if you don't know the very first place it was published, otherwise it could fall foul of our plagiarism policy... Thanks :)

Comment: Our school gave us this puzzle written on a piece of paper.
I think I solved this.
First I draw a 5 cm line then I marked 4 on that then I put the 0 mark of the ruler on 4 on the line and then I added a 2cm line to my previeus line !

Answer (score 3):

This solution seems to be a bit too simple:

> Draw from 2 to 5 (which is 3 cm long). Shift the ruler 3cm to the right so that the 2-mark is at the end of your line, and again draw from 2 to 5 to extend your line by another 3cm.

Comment: @msh210 You do have to keep the ruler parallel to the line you have already drawn, but as you have the part of the ruler between the 0 and 2 markings along the drawn line, that is no problem in practice. If you must do it perfectly, you need to put a second pencil at about the half-way point so that you can then slide the ruler along both pencils.

Answer (score 0):

First draw 5 cm, back up 2 (now you have 3 cm marked), do the same again. Now you have 6 cm marked.